# How to reformat date from 26-MAY-20 03.43.48.861000000 to 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'?

Tags: python, datetime

How would I convert `'26-MAY-20 03.43.48.861000000'` into `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'` using `datetime` in Python ?

Comment: My advice is to use regular expressions to extract the bits of the original date (i.e., "26", "MAY", "20", etc.), map those to a regularized form (e.g. "MAY" --> "05", "20" --> "2020"), paste the regularized stuff back together in ISO 8601 format, and then parse that using one of the built-in date/time libraries. I guess "861000000" represents nanoseconds? I don't know if built-in date parsers will recognize that. Unrecognized fractions of a second might be ignored or they might cause an error, I don't know, in which case you would have to cut off the too-many digits before pasting it.

Comment: @RobertDodier: numpy's [datetime64](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html) can hold nanoseconds; but I think for most datetime processing applications, they are irrelevant since accuracy is in the microsecond range at best. For the question here, simply truncating the string to microseconds and using `strptime` directly seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: @MrFuppes Yeah, probably nanoseconds is irrelevant, but then again maybe not. Not knowing the origin or destination of these data, I like to try to preserve all information, in case it becomes relevant at a later stage. Anyway the business I mentioned about string mungeing is probably needless complexity; a more workable approach is to use strptime or pandas.to_datetime as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

So big picture, the goal is to create a date object out of the first string, and then format the date into the second string.

[datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) will be your best friend here, along with [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

By referencing the library's [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), we can put together a format of the first string.

```py
from datetime import datetime

# I don't know why your datetime doesn't conform to the 1989 C standard but I'm just truncating it
may_26 = datetime.strptime('26-MAY-20 03.43.48.861000000'[:-3], "%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f")

output = datetime.strftime(may_26, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I am making a few assumptions for you in the formatting, like assuming your datetime is on 24hr format, and stuff, so definitely check for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.to_datetime` would also parse the nanoseconds (I've modified the timestring to have some...):

```
import pandas as pd
t = pd.to_datetime('26-MAY-20 03.43.48.861000100', format="%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f")

t
Out[41]: Timestamp('2020-05-26 03:43:48.861000100')

t.microsecond
Out[42]: 861000

t.nanosecond
Out[43]: 100
```